# Regarding Bootstrap Brand Position

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

[image: Current Navbar]

The picture shows the current position of my navbar. I want to shift the "Store 2.0" to the center but that isn't happening. I am attaching my code. Please help.

[image: Navbar HTML]

Comment: instead of img you should provide your code this way it is easier for others to edit it and solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not adding you code here is demo code which you can use

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

And the css

```
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:3;
}
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jr6cxrgs/1/)